# $wpdb->base_prefix not get parent site prefix in multisite

Tags: multisite

I am using three site multi-site installation.

When I use `$wpdb->base_prefix` some time it gives network site prefix instead of giving base site prefix. Any one face this problem? Can you please give any suggestion?

Comment: Are you looking for `$wpdb->prefix` instead? If you can post some of the relevant code, we may have a better chance of helping you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$wpdb->base_prefix` gets the original prefix (ie, the 'root' site in a Multisite installation). It was added in Version 3.0.0, right when Multisite became a part of WordPress core.

`$wpdb->prefix` will get the prefix for the current site in a Multisite installation.

Per [the documentation for the `wpdb` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/):

> **$prefix**
> The assigned WordPress table prefix for the site.
>
> **$base_prefix**
> The original prefix as defined in `wp-config.php`. *For multi-site: Use if you want to get the prefix without the blog number appended.*

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 2):

Try [$wpdb->get_blog_prefix](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_blog_prefix/) like below:

```
$base_prefix = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix(0);
```

And use `$base_prefix` as base prefix.

Let me know if this is not work for you.